# ASP.net URL Rewrite subdirectory to external URL

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-6

I need to URL Rewrite a subdirectory to an external domain.

Example: When visiting "https://example1.com/test", "https://example2.com/hello" should open. The URL should still be "https://example1.com/test".

I tried to solve this by adding a Rewrite rule in web.config, but it don't works. Here is the Rewrite rule I made:

```
<rule name="TestRule" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^test(/.*)?$" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="https://example2.com/hello" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59 Mistake 3 is very common.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to redirect the incoming request to another domain by using Rewrite action type (stay the old URL in the browser address bar), we need to install `Application Request Routing` module.
https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing
By default, Rewrite action only forwards these requests to the same domain, therefore, we only can specify a URL path in the `Rewrite URL` field.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#rewrite-action
Otherwise, Redirecting the incoming request to another domain will cause a 404 error. 
After we installed the ARR extension, enable Reverse Proxy functionality following the below steps.
[image]
[image]
Here is an official example.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing
Finally, please refer to the below configuration.

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Myrules" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="/test.*" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="https://www.bing.com/maps" appendQueryString="false" logRewrittenUrl="false" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

It will redirect the requests that has “/test” segment to the https://www.bing.com/maps.
[image]
If we want to complete the task without installing ARR extension, we have to use Redirect action type. The URL in the browser address bar will change while we access the qualified URL.

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Myrules" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="/test.*" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.bing.com/maps" appendQueryString="false" logRewrittenUrl="false" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.