# URL Rewrite giving 404

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I have subdomain with an A record to my IIS Server:

sub.domain.com

The IIS server has a binding for sub.domain.com and a cert for *.domain.com

What we need is when someone goes to sub.domain.com it takes them to another site but masks the URL and keeps the SSL.  The destination page has in its SAN cert sub.domain.com.

Tried a forward on Godaddy which works but it doesn't keep the SSL and we get cert issues.  So thought was to point to our server to pass SSL and then redirect it.  I tried a URL Rewrite but it's giving a 404.

URL Rewrite:

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <clear />
            <rule name="Pay Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)?sub\.domain\.com$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.domain2.com/cgsdesktop/PaymentLanding/UniversalPortal" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

I just need to know how to get this done.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```xml
<rules>
    <rule name="Pay Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^sub.domain.com$" ignoreCase="true"/>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.sub.domain.com$" ignoreCase="true"/>
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.domain2.com/cgsdesktop/PaymentLanding/UniversalPortal" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
</rules>
```

use `sub.domain.com` instead of `sub\.domain\.com`.

[This article](https://www.bisend.com/blog/top-iis-rewrite-rules) contains some useful recipes on IIS redirect/rewrite rules.

Comment: Still gives a 404

Comment: <rule name="Pay Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^sub.domain.com$" />
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.sub.domain.com$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.domain2.com/cgsdesktop/PaymentLanding/UniversalPortal" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>

Answer (score 0):

In order to mask the URL and keep the SSL in the browser bar, we need to create URL Rewrite action rules of URL Rewrite extension.
[image]
However, URL Rewrite action only supports to redirect the request to the same domain by default. We have to install the Application Request Routing extension when redirecting the request to another website.
https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing
or we will get an Http 404 error.
See my preceding post for more details.
[ASP.net URL Rewrite subdirectory to external URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62330947/asp-net-url-rewrite-subdirectory-to-external-url/62341534#62341534)
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.